# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'radix'

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, radix

I tried to install py-radix lib via pip. It was installed successfully, but when I tried to import radix in my python code in jupyter notebook I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> import radix
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'radix'

I am currently trying to make this code run on windows and I used Ubuntu to install py-radix. I have this code running on my mac perfectly fine but for some reason I can't seem to make this work in windows. any help?
Also I have python3.8 installed.
I should also note that I have looked at similar posts and tried their solutions but I have run out of ideas and would appreciate any help!

Comment: If you installed it using pip, did you use the pip script provided by the [virtual enviromnent](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-virtual-environment) (venv)?

Comment: I looked at the website and ran the suggested code but it doesn't seem to help, or maybe I;m not understanding it well? I would really appreciate some clarification or a brief explanation.

Comment: python development is largely centered around virtual environments (venv). You can install packages within these environments which are accessible only within those environments when you activate the venv. You can also install packages outside of that for more general use on your machine, and are not visible within the venv. If you are running the program from your IDE it is likey lauynching the program from within the venv, and youll need to install it to the venv.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough repose! I looked and the package has been installed in the env folder along with other packages such as pip. Would there be something else that would cause a problem like this? It has been successfully installed but it I can't import that package.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install py-radix in the ubuntu or did you install it in window's. Becuase it if you didn't install it in windows you can open a cmd and type `pip install py-radix`

Comment: I tried installing it using windows powershell but it says "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1." Is there a way to install it without using command prompt or powershell?

Comment: I personally don't know a way to install a python module with cmd or powershell, why would you want to install python module's without them?

Comment: So it seems like I successfully install py-radix-0.10.0, as the output of cmd suggests. but As I try to run my python code on Jupyter notebook it still says "
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'radix' " Any ideas on what could be causing it?
Also, with my mac I've always installed them using terminal so it seemed easy to use powershell to install it here. but as my previous statement says it just seems like it's not working well even though it says it was successfully installed.

Comment: In which app are you using the Jupyter notebook and did you import the module?

Comment: Im using anaconda, and yes in my code I have "import radix"

Comment: I'm not very experienced with anaconda, would you mind using a regular python install

Comment: Try restarting the `Kernel` of your python notebook after the successful installation of the library.

Comment: I was unsure what you meant by kernel but running "import radix" on the python IDLE shell was successful and didn't say any errors. Why wouldn't this work on Jupyter notebook though?

Comment: If you want you can use the Jupyter notebooks in vscode those should 100% work

Comment: I downloaded vscode and opened my file in there and tried to run it, but I keep having the same issue. It says: " No module named 'radix' " :(

Comment: Is there a way I could install it without using command line? like install it exactly where I have to without using cmd?

Comment: From my knowledge the only way to install python modules is with the command line, which python version did you chose in vscode?